# Simply connected linear algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Following is what I understand regarding the simply connected linear algebraic groups afer reading some definition in Hochschild's 'Basic Theory of Algebraic Groups' :

(I don't know about fundamental group)

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over a field $F$ of characterstic zero. Then $G$ is said to be simply connected if any surjective homomorphism of algebraic groups 
$$\phi : H \to G$$
where Ker $\phi$ is finite turns out to be an isomorphism.

Now, $G$ being defined over $F$ means the defining equations have coefficients in $F$. However, $G$ has points coming from $F^n$ as well as $K^n$ where $K$ is some extension of $F$. Let us denote the $F$-points in $G$ by $G_F$.

Following are my questions:

1. What can be say about the simple-connectness of $G_F$? Is this simply connected as well ? I would appreciate if you could refer to some results leading to the conclusion.
2. What about the Lie algebra of $G_F$? Is $Lie(G) \cong Lie(G_F)$?

I do not know much algebraic geometry and these type of results are coming in a paper which I am reading. Please help me out. I would appreciate if the explanation is simple and detailed.

Thanks !